# Rounding up a binary number

Tags: numerical-methods, binary, floating-point

I just converted the fraction $\frac{3}{5}$ to the following floating point binary number: $(1.001100110011001100110011\cdots)_{2}\times 2^{-1}$.

Now, I am trying to find the two nearest machine numbers to 23 places to the right of the binary point.

The lower bound can be found by simply chopping after 23 places: $x_{\_}=(1.00110011001100110011001)_{2}\times 2^{-1}$.

The upper bound needs to be done by rounding up, but how do I round up $(1.001100110011001100110011\cdots)_{2}\times 2^{-1}$ to 23 places? Pleaes help - I am not yet comfortable working in binary.

Comment: Round just as in decimal. Add to the next place $1$ and carry over if needed.

Comment: Thank you, @user251257. I asked a related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468641/computing-relative-roundoff-error-of-a-correctly-rounded-binary-number

Do you think you could take a look? Thanks.